# When should we use -ing or infinitive verbs?

Tags: verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive

I am in doubt about what is the correct form of the verbs *remember* and *understand* in the options to the first question below:

> Which is more difficult in learning a second language?
>
> 1. Remembering vocabulary or understanding native speakers? (Gerund)
> 2. To remember vocabulary or to understand native speakers? (To-infinitive)
> 3. Remember vocabulary or understand native speakers? (Bare infinitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remembering vocabulary or understanding native speakers?* (Gerund) is significantly better than either (2) or (3).

A fourth option is possible: *To remember vocabulary or understand native speakers?* (Mixed)